# Adding an image at the end of a link in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project for class, and it asks to make a navigation bar like this:

[image]

20px padding between each div, 20px for padding between the box around it etc..

I'm having trouble adding the little arrow image after my text in the links, my code is below, I was given the .png file of the arrow, and everything looks fine before adding the arrow, but once I add the arrow to the a:after line of code at the bottom of this page, it makes everything distorted:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6242Sk3.png]

***How do I fix this??***

HTML:

```
    <div id="left">
            <h2>Pick a Platform!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="green" href="#">Steam</a></li>
                <li><a class="orange" href="#">iPad</a></li>
                <li><a class="green" href="#">XBox One</a></li>
                <li><a class="orange" href="#">PlayStation 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="lastChild"  href="#">Wii U</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#left ul {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#left ul .orange {
    background-color: #DC9B25;
}

#left ul .green {
    background-color: #657761;
}

#left ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

#left ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#left ul li a.lastChild {
    border-bottom: transparent;
    background-color: #657761;
}
```

I researched a bit and found that this is what you use to add an image to the end of a link:

```
#left ul li a:after {
    content: url(arrow.png);
}
```

ADDED JSFiddle CODE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/502j2qqn/

Comment: give us jsFiddle code...

Comment: @Grasper, why? StackOverflow has that feature built in now. Give us a runnable code snippet! :)

Comment: @Grasper sorry im new

Comment: The main problem, is that the image you have is very large, so it pushes down all the other content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem with using :after is that it is not as cross browser compatible as using tradional background. Your code will work, the :after Pseudo element just needs to be styled appropriately, but your also adding more elements to the DOM using this, which increases load time and is really just unnecessary.

Change the css for this selector what I have below and delete the `#left ul li a:after` selector

```
#left ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ERt02Jx.png') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, but as an answer you may want to explain *why* this should be used instead of just positioning the `:after` generated content.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I understand how the code works, but I would like to know why it doesnt work.

Comment: @originalwill your `:after` code as it is works fine. You just haven't positioned the generated content to be to the right of the text.

Comment: Sorry guys, the problem with using :after is that your actually physically adding another element to the DOM, which is breaking the spacing. when you use background, your applying the image to the background of space that is already accounted for by your padding, etc. and not creating new space. Semantically, this is less confusing and more compatible cross browser than the :before/:after Pseudo elements.  will add this to the answer as well. @JamesDonnelly

Comment: @Bradley I understand now, thanks! And yes I tried to immediately but it said I had to wait.

Answer (score 0):

hi please look for the below link for the answer we can crete arrow using CSS itself

> http://jsfiddle.net/jai17/u8v6gr6a/

CSS:

```
.arrow-right {
     border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 10px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float: right;
    height: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 0;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="left">
    <h2>Pick a Platform!</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="green" href="#">Steam <div class="arrow-right"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="orange" href="#">iPad <div class="arrow-right"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="green" href="#">XBox One <div class="arrow-right"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="orange" href="#">PlayStation 4 <div class="arrow-right"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="lastChild"  href="#">Wii U <div class="arrow-right"></div></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```